# Иерархия классов(задача решена, есть нюансы)

Tags: c#, linq

Разработать иeрapхию клaccов для учeтa пeрсoнaла вузa(препoдаватель, вспoмогaтельный пepcoнaл, руководство, студент, аспирант, мaгистрант. Нa укaзaннyю дaту вывести списoк всего персoнала, cгруперованный пo категориям. Для сoтрудников вывести стаж работы.

Извинения приношу за г-код, но сроки жмут. Задача решена, нужно указать на ошибки. Если кто-то может сам исправить, буду очень признателен.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ticket312
{
    class Person {
        public int[] staj= {2,3,4};
    }
    class Prepod : Person {
        public string status = "Преподаватели:";
        public string[] firstname = { "Стас", "Олег", "Антон" };
        public string[] lastname = { "Антипов", "Доставевский", "Нестеренко" };
        public DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 1),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 2),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 3),
        };
    }
    class VspomogPers : Person {
        public string status = "Вспомогательный персонал: ";
    }

    class Uborka : VspomogPers {
        public string statusUb = "Уборщиц: ";
        public string[] firstname = { "Алена", "Полина", "Женя" };
        public string[] lastname = { "Мотвеенко", "Гагарина", "Петрова" };
        public DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 2),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 3),
        };
    }
    class Rucovodstvo : Person {
        public string status = "Руководство: ";

        public string[] firstname = { "Стас", "Олег", "Антон" };
        public string[] lastname = { "Кепа", "Лизогуб", "Макаров" };
        public DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1),
            new DateTime(2007, 10, 2),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 3),
        };
    }
    class Student : Person {
        public string status = "Студент: ";
        public string[] firstname = { "Стас", "Олег", "Антон" };
        public string[] lastname = { "Ab4", "Cd4", "Ee4" };
        public DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 2),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 3),
        };
    }
    class Aspirant : Person {
        public string status = "Аспиранты: ";
        public string[] firstname = { "Стас", "Олег", "Антон" };
        public string[] lastname = { "Ab5", "Cd5", "Ee5" };
        public DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 2),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 3),
        };
    }
    class Magistrant : Person {
        public string status = "Магистранты";
        public string[] firstname = { "Стас", "Олег", "Антон" };
        public string[] lastname = { "Ab6", "Cd6", "Ee6" };
        public DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 1),
            new DateTime(2017, 10, 2),
            new DateTime(2011, 10, 3),
        };
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VspomogPers vspomogPers = new VspomogPers();
            Prepod prepod = new Prepod();
            Rucovodstvo rucovodstvo = new Rucovodstvo();
            Magistrant magistrant = new Magistrant();
            Student student = new Student();
            Aspirant aspirant = new Aspirant();
            Uborka uborka = new Uborka();
            DateTime defaultDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 10, 3);

            Console.WriteLine(prepod.status);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (prepod.dateTimes[i] < defaultDateTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} {1} Стаж {2}", prepod.firstname[i], prepod.lastname[i], prepod.staj[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(uborka.status);
            Console.WriteLine(uborka.statusUb);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (uborka.dateTimes[i] < defaultDateTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} {1} Стаж {2}", uborka.firstname[i], uborka.lastname[i], uborka.staj[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(rucovodstvo.status);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (rucovodstvo.dateTimes[i] < defaultDateTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} {1} Стаж {2}", rucovodstvo.firstname[i], rucovodstvo.lastname[i], rucovodstvo.staj[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(magistrant.status);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (magistrant.dateTimes[i] < defaultDateTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} {1} Стаж {2}", magistrant.firstname[i], magistrant.lastname[i], magistrant.staj[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(student.status);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (student.dateTimes[i] < defaultDateTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} {1} Стаж {2}", student.firstname[i], student.lastname[i], student.staj[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(aspirant.status);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (aspirant.dateTimes[i] < defaultDateTime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} {1} Стаж {2}", aspirant.firstname[i], aspirant.lastname[i], aspirant.staj[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну для начала что за ужас: имена в одном массиве, фамилии в другом, даты (?) в третьем. Каждое имя — это свойство _одного_ преподавателя.

Comment: какого рода ошибки?

Comment: @VladD, а может это оптимизация для хранения не трех, а 9 человек!

Comment: Затем. Использование транслита (`Prepod` и особенно `Rucovodstvo`) — отвратительно. Найдите словарь, переведите на английский.

Comment: @Grundy: В классе с названием `Prepod` не может быть более одного имени. Если человек такое пишет, он получает законную двойку и идёт перечитывать лекции начиная с первой. Один экземпляр класса `Prepod` не имеет права моделировать трёх преподов. Раз в задании сказано «разработайте иерархию классов», то правильная семантика классов — часть задания. Пока тут семантикой и не пахнет, иерархия бессмысленная и чисто формальная.

Comment: Я имел ввиду не ошибки, просто из говнокода в человеческий не знаю как привести, как правильно сделать иерархию классов. Понимаю, что у меня она реализована неправильно, но на какую изменить не понимаю. Не понимаю, зачем она здесь вообще нужна.

Comment: @NameJ: Для начала вспомните (или найдите в лекциях), что есть класс, и какие в нём должны быть данные. Подумайте, почему в классе `Prepod` не может быть три имени ни в коем случае. Это важная часть задания; если вы этого не поймёте, считайте, что семестр проучились зря.

Comment: Ну раз я сюда обратился, значит нигде не нашел ответа на свой вопрос, и задания похожего, чтобы исправить ошибки, тоже не нашел. Объясните хотябы как иерархию классов расписать. Со стилем кода я все понимаю, это бдет исправлено

Comment: Вопрос не в стиле кода. Вопрос в том, какие данные должны, а какие не должны лежать в классе `Prepod`. Вы всё же посмотрите, что ваши лекции об этом говорят.

Comment: а что за поле _dateTimes_?

Comment: @Grundy, в нем хранится дата зачисления, поступления, иными словами дата появления в заведении, а defaultDateTimes -- дата, на которую вывести нужно чисто имеющихся людей(персонала, студентов и т.п.)

Answer (score 4):

В вашем коде настолько сильно продемонстрировано непонимание принципов ООП, что я думаю -- отправление на пересдачу очень реально.

Во-первых, вы храните информацию о преподавателях в самом классе `Prepod`, в то время как для этого нужно использовать `Prepod[]` (`List<Prepod>` или другие варианты). Посмотрите на образец для вдохновения:

```
void Main()
{
    var employee1 = new Employee { FirstName = "Иван", LastName = "Иванов" };
    var employee2 = new Employee { FirstName = "Олег", LastName = "Ольшанский" };
    var employee3 = new Employee { FirstName = "Петр", LastName = "Петров" };

    var employees = new Employee[] { employee1, employee2, employee3 };

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Employee: {employee.LastName} {employee.FirstName}");
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Во-вторых, вы не понимаете иерархию классов. Вы не понимаете, что `FistName` и `LastName` должны находиться не на уровне класса `Teacher` (а также -- `Student`, `Bachelor` и даже не на уровне класса `Employee`), но на уровне класса `Person`, от которого начинается иерархия наследования классов.

Рекомендую для начала разобраться хотя бы с этими двумя пунктами, потому что сейчас ваша программа крайне слабо соотносится с "разработайте иерархию классов".

Comment: Cпасибо, что пояснили нубу тогда )

Answer (score 0):

Перечисление и сам класс

```
enum Statuses
{
    Преподаватели,
    Уборщицы,
    Руководство,
    Аспиранты,
    Магистранты,
    Студенты
}
class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime WorkExperience { get; set; }
    public Statuses Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DefaultDate
    {
        get { return new DateTime(2014, 10, 3); }
    }
}
```

Работа

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employees = new Employee[2];
        employees[0] = new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Andrei",
            LastName = "Demov",
            WorkExperience = new DateTime(2010, 10, 3),
            Status = 0
        };
        employees[1] = new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Dima",
            LastName = "Kudov",
            WorkExperience = new DateTime(2013, 10, 3),
            Status = (Statuses)1
        };

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            if (employee.WorkExperience < employee.DefaultDate)
            {
                DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
                TimeSpan timeSpan = employee.DefaultDate.Subtract(employee.WorkExperience);
                int years = (zeroTime + timeSpan).Year - 1;

                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {employee.Status}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Employee: {employee.LastName} {employee.FirstName} WorkExperience: {years}");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Ну и сам результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]